# Is string Object Created in Heap if we use new String("abcd")

Tags: java

```
    String s1 = new String("anil");
    String s2 = s1.toUpperCase();
    String s3 = s1.toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(s1 == s2);
    System.out.println(s1 == s3);
```

if string object created in heap then both are false.But it gives false,true.

Comment: s3 will be pointing to the same string as s1. So it is true. check implementation of toLowerCase();

Comment: @WhoAmi No such behaviour is *specified* for toLowerCase(), so it cannot be relied on.

Answer (score 3):

```
String s1 = new String("anil");
```

This statement creates a new object

And this ,

```
String s3 = s1.toLowerCase();
```

points the location of 1st object that is `s1`

And thats the reason you are getting `true` for second condition

Also see [how java handles strings](http://java.dzone.com/articles/string-memory-internals) to get a clear understanding

Hope this helps!!

Comment: +1.. because toLowerCase returns the same String if there are no uppercase characters.

Comment: @WhoAmI +1 to the comment , should be added to the answer

Answer (score 1):

There are *four* String objects here:

- the literal, created by the compiler and classloader
- s1, created by new String()
- s2, created by toUpperCase()
- s3, created by toLowerCase().

No two of them are equal via the == operator.

***Except*** that toLowerCase() may return the same object if it is already lowercase. There's nothing in the Javadoc about that, so any such behaviour in an implementation cannot be relied on.

Answer (score 0):

Here S1 object will be created in heap. Its value is stored in the constant string pool.

S2 is String literal not an object. So first JVM will check whether the string is there in constant pool. If String is there constant pool it will not create new object. It will return reference of the object available.

Here the s1.toUpper will return "ANIL". "ANIL" is not in the constant pool. so new object will be created. and comparing it with s1 (using'==') give false.

Same for S3. But for S3 it wont create new object as "anil" is already there in constant pool.
so will return the reference of S1. So it gives true.

Study the following link

[Study this](http://www.javatpoint.com/string-handling-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the toLowerCase() method in String class.

1. It calls `toLowerCase(Locale locale)`
2. `toLowerCase(Locale locale)` inturn uses `Character.toLowerCase(c)`
3. `Character.toLowerCase(c)` in Character class has this comment -

   - @param   ch   the character to be converted.
   - @return  the lowercase equivalent of the character, if any;
   - otherwise, the character itself.

Comment: This code may help you how? What is it?

Comment: @EJP - My bad. I've edited my answer. The above code made me think that toLowercase() of String won't do anything if char is already in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1:** String with `Capital First Letter`.

```
> String s1 = new String("Ajay")
String s2 = s1.toUpperCase()
String s3 = s1.toLowerCase()
System.out.println s1 == s2
System.out.println s1 == s3
false
false
```

**Case 2:** String with `Small First Letter`.

```
> String s1 = new String("ajay")
String s2 = s1.toUpperCase()
String s3 = s1.toLowerCase()
System.out.println s1 == s2
System.out.println s1 == s3
false
true
```

in *Case 1*, since the string has **capital letter**, converting to **lowercase** will yield a **new object hence a new reference** for it while in *Case 2* **small first letter** after converting to lowercase will still point to the same object because the original object was same hence **creating two references for the same object**.

You can see the output from the `Groovy Shell` pretty clear.